# load image in canvas fail under Internet Explorer 9 and opera

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, canvas, opera

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <script src="resources/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"> </script>
        ...
        ...
        <script>
            ...
            ...
            function draw(screen, data) {  
                if (screen.document.getElementById("screen") == null){
                    screen.document.write('<div id="screen" style="width:' +
                    data.maxX + '; height:' + data.maxY + '; margin: auto;" >' +
                    '<canvas id="screenCanvas" width=' + data.maxX + ' height=' + 
                    data.maxY + 'style="border:2px solid #000000;color:#000000;" > </canvas></div>');
                }
                var canvas = screen.document.getElementById('screenCanvas');
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');  
                var tileY = 0;
                var tileX = 0;
                var counter = 0;
                var tileWidth = data.tileWidth;
                var tileHeight = data.tileHeight;
                for (var i=0;i<(data.maxX/data.tileWidth);i++){  
                    for (var j=0;j<(data.maxY/data.tileHeight);j++){  
                        var img = new Image();  
                        img.onload = (function(img, tileX, tileY, tileWidth, tileHeight){
                            return function() {
                                context.drawImage(img,tileX, tileY, tileWidth, tileHeight);
                            }
                        })(img, tileX, tileY, tileWidth, tileHeight);  
                        img.src = "http://myserver:8080/images/screen/tile/" + 
                                   data.tiles[counter].imageId; 
                        tileX = tileX + parseInt(data.tileWidth); 
                        counter ++; 
                     } 
                    tileY = tileY + parseInt(data.tileHeight); 
                    tileX = 0;
                }  
            }
            ...
            ...
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

i call this function  when i open a new window to draw a canvas in the new window contains an array of images.

**problem:**

1- Internet explorer 9: draw canvas but it didn't draw images (since the border that i set in the style of the canvas appears).

2- when IE try to get image this error appears

```
SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught 
index.html, line 1 character 1
```

3- Opera 12: it didn't display canvas.

**Note:**

1- this function works fine with Firefox, google chrome, and safari.

2- i am sure that internet explorer are not in compatibility view (F12) and not Quirks mode (it is standards).

any help?

Comment: Good presentation of a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <script src="resources/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"> </script>
        ...
        ...
        <script>
            ...
            ...
            function draw(screen, data) {  
                var canvas;
                if (screen.document.getElementById("screen") == null){
                    var canvasDiv = screen.document.createElement("div"); 
                    canvasDiv.id = "screen"; 
                    canvasDiv.style.margin = "0px auto";
                    canvasDiv.style.width = data.maxX;
                    canvasDiv.style.height = data.maxY;
                    canvasDiv.style.border='2px solid black';
                    screen.document.body.appendChild(canvasDiv); 

                    canvas = screen.document.createElement('canvas');
                    canvas.setAttribute('width', data.maxX);
                    canvas.setAttribute('height', data.maxY);
                    canvas.setAttribute('id', 'screenCanvas');
                    canvasDiv.appendChild(canvas);
                    if(typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
                        canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
                    }
                }else{
                    canvas = screen.document.getElementById('screenCanvas');
                }

                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');  
                var tileY = 0;
                var tileX = 0;
                var counter = 0;
                var tileWidth = data.tileWidth;
                var tileHeight = data.tileHeight;
                for (var i=0;i<(data.maxX/data.tileWidth);i++){  
                    for (var j=0;j<(data.maxY/data.tileHeight);j++){  
                        var img = new Image();  
                        img.onload = (function(img, tileX, tileY, tileWidth, tileHeight){
                            return function() {
                                context.drawImage(img,tileX, tileY, tileWidth, tileHeight);
                            }
                        })(img, tileX, tileY, tileWidth, tileHeight);  
                        img.src = "http://myserver:8080/images/screen/tile/" + 
                                   data.tiles[counter].imageId; 
                        tileX = tileX + parseInt(data.tileWidth); 
                        counter ++; 
                     } 
                    tileY = tileY + parseInt(data.tileHeight); 
                    tileX = 0;
                }  
            }
            ...
            ...
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

**reference:** [www.williammalone.com](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/)

since IE doesn't know what the canvas tag means, and if we used that in our markup, IE would serve us an entrée of error. Instead we create a canvas element in JavaScript.

hope this help you

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.. interesting. I think i got a similar problem i'll just tag onto this stack.

After my page is loaded, a function is called to load an image (.png) in an already created canvas element. Half the time in IE this image is not loaded. I gotta hit refresh and eventually it shows up. In firefox & chrome it works on the first try. Sometimes it works on the first try in IE too, but this irregularity is killing me....

```
function loadCanvas(dataURL) {
   var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   X_max = parseInt($("#container").css('width'));
   Y_max = parseInt($("#container").css('height'));

   canvas.width = X_max;
   canvas.height = Y_max;

   ctx.fillStyle="white";
   ctx.fillRect(0, 0, X_max, Y_max);


   // load image from data url
   var imageObj = new Image;

   imageObj.onload = function() {
   ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
   };

   imageObj.src = dataURL;
}
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I'm getting something very similar in IE9.  Does it arrive at the drawImage ok?

Comment: Nope - havent figured it out. IE doesnt seem to like canvas. One of my alternatives is just loading the png as a background image and telling the user 'no painting for you, mr IE user'. 

not sure if it arrives at the drawimage ok -> the function is called when document is loaded ... but the image it is loading is often a few hundred kb big .. and i am thinking that if the 'document' gets interrupted with another request somewhere (i got a sync loop) before it finishes loading, it kills the canvas request. Gotta explore it more, i guess - was hoping for quick help here

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling the `draw` function after page load, then you will have to replace the `document.write(...)` as it will create a new page and IE won't complete the image onload handler (unlike as at least chrome).

```
$("body").append('<div id="screen" style="width:' +
                    data.maxX + 'px; height:' + data.maxY + 'px; margin: auto;" >' +
                    '<canvas id="screenCanvas" width=' + data.maxX + ' height=' + 
                    data.maxY + style="border:2px solid #000000;color:#000000;"></canvas</div>')
```

Comment: how can use $("body").append(....); with in new window (as i mention above, i want to add canvas inside a new window called screen)?

Comment: IE9 support canvas, that's true but i was facing the same problem, and i solved it with my posted answer.